# how to merge all possible spaces in the text in C

Tags: c, pointers, whitespace

The purpose of the function is to merge all possible whitespaces in the string into one space. The code I wrote works except for one string where it breaks.

```c
void merge_whitespace(char *str) {
     char *d = str;

  while(*str != '\0') {
        while (*str == '\t' || *str == '\r' || *str == '\n' || *str =='\f' || *str =='\v' || (*str == ' ' && *(str+1) == ' ')) {
          str++;
        }
      *d++ = *str++;
  }
    *d = '\0';
 }   


test
[This  is another test.     Now we 

 have all kinds of    white space   ]

My output is:
[This is another test. Now we  have all kinds of white space ]


but should be:

[This is another test. Now we have all kinds of white space ]

So the problem is in the string test, it prints two spaces instead of one.
```

Comment: At first glance you don't combine end of line characters with spaces. So you'll have a space from before the end of line and one from after.

Comment: Ditto you don't replace an end of line with a space, so if you had "one\ntwo" you'd end up with "onetwo" not "one two".

Comment: And you can use `isspace(*str)` to test if a character is whitespace rather than listing all possibilities. According to [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/) it uses the same set of characters that you have in your list for the default locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text goes like

```
" \n "
```

So, when the 1st whitespace gets encountered, it checks

```
(*str == ' ' && *(str+1) == ' ')
```

str indeed equals ' ', but str+1 equals '\n', not ' '. So, this is how it fails.

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot!